# DataStax Bulk Loader for Apache Cassandra isn't installing on Windows

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I'm trying to install DataStax Bulk Loader on my Windows machine in order to import json file to Cassandra databse. I just follow the installation instructions from the official webstie. It's just unpack the folder. Printing `dsbulk`from any catalogue into **cmd** prints the following result:  `"dsbulk" is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.` However I added `C:\DSBulk\dsbulk-1.7.0\bin` into PATH variables. Anyone who faced with this problem what did you do? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change into the `bin/` directory where you unzipped the package. For example:

```
C:> cd C:\DSBulk\dsbulk-1.7.0\bin
```

Then run the `dsbulk.cmd` from there.

NOTE: Make sure you have both the classpath and Java home set in your environment. Cheers!